# jQuery mobile select list does not work on device/emulator

Tags: jquery, list, select, mobile

I'm currently working on a form in my jquery mobile/phonegap app. Within this form I have two select lists. They both work fine in my desktop-browsers (firefox, safari, chrome).

The strange thing is, that the first one also opens properly on the emulator and on the device and I can choose and select an option from it. The second one won`t open the option list on neither one for some reaseon.

I already tried to add any of jQM additional properties like: data-native-menu="false" and so on. And yes, when I use it it suddenly works, BUT of course it changes the appearance of my second select list and doesn't match the first one anymore.

What I don't understand is, why is it working on the first list, but not on the second?

Here is the important snippet fom my form:

```
<!-- first select: works! -->
<h2>headline 1</h2>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
      <div id="titleSelectContainer" class="fullWidth form-lines clearFix">
        <div class="oneQuarter">
          <label class="labels">Anrede</label>
        </div>
        <select id="titelSelect" class="inputFields" name="titelSelect" data-mini="true">
          <option value="standard" data-placeholder="true">-- Bitte wählen --</option>
          <option value="Mr.">Herr</option>
          <option value="Mrs.">Frau</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- second: does not work! -->
<h2>headline 2</h2>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  <li class="payOptions">
    <select class="inputFields payDDL" name="pay" id="paySelect" data-mini="true">
      <option value="standard" data-placeholder="true">-- Bitte wählen --</option>
      <option value="creditcard">Kreditkarte</option>
      <option value="invoice">Rechnung</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

any solutions?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for it? In particular - I'm interested in finding out what do the classes 'payOptions', 'inputFields' and 'payDDL' do.

Comment: Hi Jagtesh,

thanks for your reply. Even though I found a solution myself, I wanted to put up the code on js fiddle. The problem is, that the whole thing implements lots of stuff. So if I take out a snipped it doesn't look and behave right. Anyway, here is what I tried to take out of it and hope all neccessary is there: http://jsfiddle.net/2gQ6V/

But it's like I said: It does work on the a desktop-browser, but not in Android. By the way, the "payDDL" class was only a left over when I tried to fix it, but it didn't have any influence. So I took that out.

Comment: Glad you could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got around it by deleting the ul around it and adjustig the style of the remaining select list to the input fields above.

conclusion: seems like jQM selectfields don't work right within an ul in Android. Here is my final code:

```
<h2>Zahlungsart</h2>
  <div id="paymentSelectContainer">
      <select name="pay" id="paySelect">
          <option value="standard" data-placeholder="true">-- Bitte wählen --</option>
          <option value="creditcard">Kreditkarte</option>
          <option value="invoice">Rechnung</option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Edit: My solution worked on the emulator, but when I tried it on the device it wasn't yet again!

Comment: Don't post any incomplete solution! It may make confused others.Thanks